# Wordpress Select Navigation Menu Item

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

I am building a custom Wordpress plugin where I would like to highlight the item on the navigation menu corresponding to the plugin, either by the text in contains or the URL, whichever...

Is there a filter or action which I can hook into to select the appropriate menu item? My searching has been fruitless.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how is our menu build it but,

You may try this snippet of code to do what you want.

```
<ul>
<li<?php 
                if (is_page('YourPlugin')) 
                { 
                echo " id=\"current\"";
                }?>>
                <a href="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/YourPlugin">Plugin</a>
        </li>
</ul>
```

Now, you can change id=\"current\"" with any ID that have custom CSS